# DB2 table not found when schema is mentioned in Jndi, but same works from normal db connection

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, db2, jndi

When I am trying to connect to DB2 using schema definition in connection url it works fine
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2:/server:xxxx/ins:currentSchema=DEVSCHEMA;

but when the same is tried from tomcat jndi using

```
    <Resource 
        auth="Container" 
        defaultAutoCommit="false" 
        driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
        initialSize="10" 
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="80" 
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" 
        minIdle="30" 
        name="jdbc/connDB" 
        password="xxxxxxx" 
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="55" 
        testOnBorrow="true" 
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:db2:/server:xxxx/ins:currentSchema=DEVSCHEMA;" 
        username="xxxxx" 
        validationInterval="34000" 
        validationQuery="select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"/>
```

I get error
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DEVSCHEMA.tablename, DRIVER=4.31.10

The jar used in the classpath is jcc-11.5.7.0.jar, ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar, for both instances.

Using springboot version 2.7.4

Is there any configuration that needs to be added to fix the issue.

Comment: Is this a case sensitive problem?  Try uppercase if using doubquotes, or use the exact same case for the schema that appears in the Db2 catalog.

Comment: Do you have a table in devschema named tablename?

Comment: It is working fine when I am not using jndi, and connecting directly using userid and password using the same url. We developed our application first using direct DB connection then step 2 was to use jndi during integration which failing. The table exist in the schema. The schema name is in caps, I have updated the question as well.